# Java based Webmail solutions

Tags: java, webmail

I need to provide email sending and receiving capabilities within my java web-application. Think of it as providing a lightweight IMAP client embedded within the application.

Are there any good java based open-source libraries/projects/webmail solutions that provide similar functionality?

Please note that I don't want to emails would still be retrieved from the email server external to my application, I just need to provide an interface (matching the rest of my application) and accessible from within the application, to carry out common email operations such as reading and sending emails.

Regards,

-Deepak

Comment: I didn't specify it clearly, rather than looking for a library, I am looking for a web-application/component, that I can embed inside my java application so that I don't even have to worry about creating the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "canonical" Java IMAP solution would, in my experience, be [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/). And yes, that's open-source now, too: https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository/javax.mail/java-sources/

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [Open Source Web Mail Clients in Java](http://java-sources.org/open-source/web-mail)

Answer (score 1):

**Webmail System with chat module developed in java/j2ee (AJAX based)**

For more information visit: http://jtechnoprojects.blogspot.com/p/webmail-system-with-chating-ajax-based.html

Demo Webmail System is a fully functional webmail system like gmail that provides all the webmail functionality.

It also includes chat module like in gmail, yahoo that provides intuitive chat functionality. It can be useful for schools, colleges, universities and other organizations.

**Webmail system features:**

All the basic functions like in any other webmail system.

- Compose, forward, forward with
  attachment, reply, reply with
  attachment, delete, move to folder,
  mark as read, mark as unread, mark as
  spam etc...
- Intuitive chat module
- comprehensive Address Book
- AJAX based attachment support like in
  gmail
- Manage mails by creating folders
- Fully AJAX based application

**Technology used:**

- JAVA (Java Mail API, Multithreading),
  JSP, Servlet, ZK
- HMailserver email server
- Mysql Database

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for 'java IMAP library' gave me
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-imap.asp

Looks like all the dreams, that I'm aware you have, have come true :)

Comment: But, it doesn't look like it's open-source, and furthermore, it looks quite pricey!

Comment: I've run across that library before.  Looks quite nice, but I haven't yet had an e-mail issue that wasn't solved just as easily with JavaMail.  However, someday I'll probably hit the limits with JavaMail...  :-)

Answer (score -1):

webmail system with chat module developed in JAVA : http://www.jtechnosoft.com/ZkMail/